# Update value after passing pointer

Tags: multithreading, sockets, pointers, tcp, mutex

I am using a TCP server to send a char array. The function `send()` takes a `char *`, but, before that, it has to listen and accept a connection. Given that, I want to send the most recent data when an incoming connection is accepted. Previously, I used two threads. One updated the value in the buffer, the other simply waited for connections, then sent data.

I understand that there can be problems with not locking a mutex, but aside from that, would this same scheme work if I passed the `char *` to a send function, rather than updating it as a global variable?

Some code to demonstrate:

```
#include <pthread.h>

char buf[BUFLEN];

void *updateBuffer(void *arg) {
    while(true) {
        getNewData(buf);
    }
}

void *sendData(void *arg) {
    //Setup socket
    while(true) {
        newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &size);
        send(newfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0);
        close(newfd);
    }
}
```

This would send the updated values whenever a new connection was established.

I want to try this:

```
#include <pthread.h>

char buf[BUFLEN];

void *updateBuffer(void *arg) {
    while(true) {
        getNewData(buf);
    }
}

void *sendData(void *arg) {
    TCPServer tcpServer;
    while(true) {
        tcpServer.send(buf);
   }
}
```

Where the function `tcpServer.send(char *)` is basically the same as `sendData()` above.

The reason for doing this is so that I can make the TCP server into a class, since I'll need to use the same code elsewhere.

From my understanding, since I am passing the pointer, it's basically the same as when I just call `send()`, since I also pass a pointer there. The value will continue to update, but the address won't change, so it should work. Please let me know if that is correct. I'm also open to new ways of doing this (without mutex locks, preferably).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the way most of us do a send, pass a pointer to a buffer either void * or char *

I would coded like this:

```
int sendData(const char * buffer, const int length) 
{
    Socket newfd;
    Int NumOfConnects=0;

    while ((newfd=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &size)) > 0)
    {
           // It would be necessary here to lock the buffer with a Mutex
            send(newfd, buffer, length, 0);
           // Release the Mutex
            close(newfd);
            NumOfConnects++;
    }

    // there is an error in the accept
    // this could be OK, 
    // if the main thread has closed the sockfd socket indicating us to quit.

    // returns the number of transfers we have done.
    return NumOfConnects;
}
```

One thing to consider about using a pointer to a buffer which is modify in another thread;

Could it be that in the middle of a send the buffer changes and the data sent is not accurate.

But that situation you've already noticed as well. Using a Mutex is suggested as you indicated.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the mutex thing could be an issue, but only if a particular byte is updating its value while being read. In any case, it's fine if the occasional value is wrong. Thanks again.